# GreenSock javascript animation with dynamic left

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

Iam trying to create quite complex animation in [GreenSock](http://greensock.com/) and I really need persist / dynamic left css animation, I try several things like array with offsets, function (with current context) instead of value, but it seems they don't accept it...

As you can see later on fiddle, problem is in this part of code:

```
/** Switch items */
tl.to(elArray[left], 1, { left: elArray[right].offset().left });
tl.to(elArray[right], 1, { left: elArray[left].offset().left });
```

Here is demo on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v4z3gm7q/4/. It much more simplier than what i really want, but it shows problem well.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the syntax to

```
tl.to(elArray[left], 1, { css:{left: elArray[right].offset().left + "px" }});
tl.to(elArray[right], 1, { css:{left: elArray[left].offset().left + "px" });
```

When you are tweening an array of elements use staggerTo like:

```
tl.staggerTo([elArray[left], elArray[right]], 0.4, { css:{top: "10px"} });
```